# How to create a list in Content View with clickable URLs in SwiftUI?

Tags: list, url, swiftui, clickable

This is a question that I couldn't find an answer for but I figured it out with friend's help eventually (there is right answer given by me lower in this thread).

I wanted to create a list based in JSON I downloaded from the GitHub website, but I couldn't find how to make the list items clickable, so that they would allow the user to see the repositories they were searching for.

Please note that this question is regarding SwiftUI, not Storyboards approach to iOS programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the WebView. The main code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {

HStack {
                    TextField("Enter search", text: $viewModel.query)
                    Button("Search") {
                        viewModel.fetchRepos()
                    }
                }
                List(viewModel.searchResults, id: \.id) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
/* the lines answering to the query start from the Link command and follow until the end */ 
                        Link(destination: URL(string: item.htmlUrl)!, label: {
                            Text(item.fullName)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        })
                    }
                }
}
```

I commented where the answer starts. And for a better understanding of the code, these are the API keys:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Root: Codable {
    let items: [Item]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let htmlUrl: String
    let fullName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case htmlUrl = "html_url"
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }
}
```

Have fun creating your clickable lists that will let your users go to the corresponding URLs :)

P.S.
In this answer the URLSession, JSONDecoder and query handling parts are missing but they would complicate it and are not crucial to this problem. You can research them on Stack Overflow in different topics :)

Answer (score -1):

Please use UITableView for Clickable ListView.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           tableView.delegate = self
           tableView.dataSource = self
      }
}
```

Comment: This is a SwiftUI topic not Storyboard one :)